# Calling a REST listener for EWS-JAVA

Tags: java, listener

I am trying to implement a listener that receives push notifications from a Exchange mail server using ews-java library. The way to do this was outlined here:

[Exchange Web Services Java APi + RESTful Push Notifications Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784552/exchange-web-services-java-api-restful-push-notifications-listener)

However this has still left me with a few questions about how to tie it all together.  I have steps 1 & 2 working. I have done a few tutorials on listener classes.

How, and where do I call the listener class from? Would it be called immediately after the subscription to push notifications?

What would the syntax of calling it look like?

What libraries are used to achieve this? It looks like:

Jersey
Tomcat

And what URL is being used to test getMsg method?

Thanks