# EWS Push Notification to no eventtype

Tags: java, notifications, push, exchangewebservices

i could implement restful push-notification successfuly.
I get from exchange-server 2010 sp1 this notification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap11:Envelope xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap11:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" Version="Exchange2010_SP1" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" />
    </soap11:Header>
    <soap11:Body>
        <m:SendNotification xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
            <m:ResponseMessages>
                <m:SendNotificationResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
                    <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
                    <m:Notification>
                        <t:SubscriptionId>HwBleGNoYW5nZTIwMTAuaW50ZXJuLmV0ZWN0dXJlLmRlEAAAABNxdZtVvMZBo13hrhv+0RuAYyI4Bd/TCA==</t:SubscriptionId>
                        <t:PreviousWatermark>AQAAAEfUnG14DdNIpJOCbGWMf80VyhopAAAAAAA=</t:PreviousWatermark>
                        <t:MoreEvents>false</t:MoreEvents>
                        <t:StatusEvent>
                            <t:Watermark>AQAAAEfUnG14DdNIpJOCbGWMf81NyhopAAAAAAE=</t:Watermark>
                        </t:StatusEvent>
                    </m:Notification>
                </m:SendNotificationResponseMessage>
            </m:ResponseMessages>
        </m:SendNotification>
    </soap11:Body>
</soap11:Envelope>
```

My question is, how can i find out, which type of event has been triggered?
When i look on notification, i dont see any information about this.
When i want to know, which item has triggered this, should i start new request to exchange-server? which information (something like id) could i use for that?
On this issue

[Exchange Web Services Java APi + RESTful Push Notifications Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784552/exchange-web-services-java-api-restful-push-notifications-listener)

you can see within function "bussines logic" type "ExchangeNotification".
This type provides eventItems, but i cant find this type within microsoft-lib. How can i find out eventtypes and retrive about item, which triggered such event?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification you posted is a StatusEvent https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa565616(v=exchg.150).aspx . The event means there has been no activity in the Mailbox these work in conjunction with statusfrequency https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2014/04/17/ews-push-what-is-the-statusfrequency-for/w.  A Real Mailbox event would be returned as one of the EventType https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa562955(v=exchg.150).aspx within the Notification Node.

Answer (score 0):

That means, that this notification is that, what i expect?
I ask about that, because i see only id of the item and kind of event.
It means, i have to start reqeust and ask for subject of this item or something like this

```
<soap11:Body>
        <m:SendNotification xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
            <m:ResponseMessages>
                <m:SendNotificationResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
                    <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
                    <m:Notification>
                        <t:SubscriptionId>HwBleGNoYW5nZTIwMTAuaW50ZXJuLmV0ZWN0dXJlLmRlEAAAADFB9tC6gnBOvVuiJgN7tSANvjtW6eHTCA==</t:SubscriptionId>
                        <t:PreviousWatermark>AQAAAEfUnG14DdNIpJOCbGWMf81bgDspAAAAAAA=</t:PreviousWatermark>
                        <t:MoreEvents>false</t:MoreEvents>
                        <t:ModifiedEvent>
                            <t:Watermark>AQAAAEfUnG14DdNIpJOCbGWMf80LgTspAAAAAAE=</t:Watermark>
                            <t:TimeStamp>2016-09-21T06:34:54Z</t:TimeStamp>
                            <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADMyMGUyNzYzLWMwMDgtNDg3ZS04NmU5LWE3Yjk2NGVkMjU5YQBGAAAAAAAIe55QGP1eQLnln3/f75mHBwDodG9Iu/DFSoolXoHr7GuBAAAA5gbCAADodG9Iu/DFSoolXoHr7GuBAAApTv9PAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAAA==" />
                            <t:ParentFolderId Id="AAMkADMyMGUyNzYzLWMwMDgtNDg3ZS04NmU5LWE3Yjk2NGVkMjU5YQAuAAAAAAAIe55QGP1eQLnln3/f75mHAQDodG9Iu/DFSoolXoHr7GuBAAAA5gbCAAA=" ChangeKey="AQAAAA==" />
                        </t:ModifiedEvent>
                    </m:Notification>
                </m:SendNotificationResponseMessage>
            </m:ResponseMessages>
        </m:SendNotification>
    </soap11:Body>
```